# Php https request for a page

Tags: php, https

I was trying to use this code:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_PORT'] !== 443 && !isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
  header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  exit;
}
```

to make my login page and register page contain **https** to use the ssl to make sure that everything is secure, but when I run the page an error message shows up **Undefined index error using $_SERVER['HTTPS']**

so I decided to use another one:

```
if ( isset( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] ) && strtolower( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] ) == "on" ) {
  $pageURL .= "s";
}
```

but it didn't work. The https didn't show up and http is only there...

any idea how to do that with php...

Thanks

**The solution is:**

```
if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on")
```

`{
    header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    exit();
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`
>     Set to a **non-empty value** if the script was queried through the HTTPS protocol.

Therefore, you should be using the following condition to check for an HTTPS connection:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
{
    // https://...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but didn't work. I, however, used another way similar. and here is the code: `if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on")
{
    header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    exit();
}`

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']`.
HTTP_PORT doesnt always return the portnumber.